# CouchDB database model

Tags: api, rest, couchdb

I have two entities:

1. Company [companyId (PK)] and
2. Employee [employeeId (PK), companyId (PK, FK)].

Is there anyway I can organize my documents in CouchDB so that I can query an employee using the following format (*$CouchDB is the URL to my CouchDB instance*) ?

```
$CouchDB/company/{companyId}/employee/{employeeId}
```

I know that we can mix both Company and Employee documents in one database and use meta field (e.g: "_type") and map/reduce to query the document we want. There is nothing wrong with "map/reduce" approach, just want to double check so that I don't miss anything.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *not* organize your documents that way. I agree, that is a very nice layout, however the short answer is that CouchDB does not support that.

Document IDs (and document URLs) are *flat*. They all share the same namespace. Another way of saying this is that the `"_id"` value in a document **must** be its primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Although [with some quirks](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1229), document `_id` can contain `/`. Then `company/COMPANYID/employee/EMPLOYEEID` is a valid id.

I often use the following scheme to build the `_id` of a document (I prefer `_`):

```
EntityName_ENTITYID
```

With this `_id`:

- I don't need `_type` field;
- I get all companies with `_all_docs?startkey="Company_"&endkey="Company_\fff0"`;
- I get all employees within a company with `_all_docs?startkey="Employee_COMPANYID_"&endkey="Employee_COMPANYID_\fff0"`;
- I avoid id conflicts between different entities.